# How to create a html page after user sign up?

Tags: python, html, server

I am working with a chat web app. In the chat app, the user will create a his account and then, the server will do the following process (all the process will be done using post request in my whole application):-

1. Save the credentials in a txt file
2. Create a html homepage for the user
3. Send a success message

The code for the server is:-

```
elif 'signup%20name?=' and "%20pwd?=" in self.path:
            users = open("users.txt", 'a+')
            usr = (self.path).replace("/signinupsignup%20name?=", '')
            usrpw = usr.replace("%20pwd?=", "<[-----=-----]>")
            usrpwd = usrpw + '\n'
            users.write(usrpwd)
            users.close()
            filenam = usrpw.replace('<[-----=-----]>', '')
            filename = '/userhome/' + filenam + '.html'
            htmlfile = open(filename, 'w')
            htmlfile.write(r'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\nmeta charset="UTF-8">\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n<title>User Home</title>\n<style>\n#navbar\n{\nbackground-color: purple;\ncolor: white;\ntext-align: center;\nposition: relative;\n}\n#chats a:hover\n{\ncolor: white;\nbackground-color: black;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<div id="navbar">\n<div id="welcome">\n<h1>Cobra Chat-Room</h1>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div id="chats">\n<!-- chats of the user -->\n<a href="#">Group 1</a><br>\<noscript></noscript>\n</body>\n</html>\n')
            self.path = '/success.html'
```

But when I run the file I get the following error:-

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 41192)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/server.py", line 427, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/server.py", line 415, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/SignUp/server.py", line 16, in do_GET
    htmlfile = open(filename, 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/userhome/ssss.html'
----------------------------------------
```

The filename of the html home-page will be `<username><password>` without any space. It will be stored in the directory named as "userhome"

(OS => Kali Linux; Pyhton version 3.9)

Answer (score 0):

its may be because the ip address you have given might be wrong

or check whether server is having a static ip

if not it might be changing

Comment: I tried this with localhost (127.0.0.1). If I will use it with my friends, etc. I will deploy it with NGROK http tunnel. The data stored in each session will be stored in the computer running this server.